# android linkfy for part of textview

Tags: android, encoding, webview

I'm using Textview to show text with URLs inside.
How to linkfy part of text? 
This tag doesn't work:

```
<a href=\"http://www.mycite.com/terms/android\"><big>current terms</big></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(Your string));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
    tv.setText(
        Html.fromHtml(
            "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
            "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
            "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```